# How to enable autobuy of Ethers in exchange of my CryptoCurrency?

Tags: contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm referring this page : https://www.ethereum.org/token#automatic-selling-and-buying

My question is that how is it possible to integrate third party in our Smart Contracts to be deployed on Ethereum Wallet ( do we have to make a http request to the third party say an exchange to give us the current prices of my currency )